# Heroku Postgres can't connect from heroku app

Tags: postgresql, heroku, go, heroku-postgres

So I have a go rest api running on Heroku. I had the free tier version but now we have moved the app to production and upgraded to a standard-0 database. None of my code changed the only thing that changed were environmental variables to connect to the database. However, when I try to connect to the database I get this error:

```
[BRONZE] [5-1] sql_error_code = 28000 FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "54.234.***.***", user "ub21ndj3*****", database "d8useg2o3****", SSL off
```

From my understanding its an SSL issue. What I don't understand is my app is running on Heroku servers so I shouldn't need to create a tls config to connect to the database and the same code was working with the previous database. Would there be another issue why I'm getting this error?

Comment: any solutions? What causes this?

Comment: @SimonFranzen I ended up switching to AWS, also because I couldn't store files in Heroku servers

Comment: haha :) ok nice shot! I think heroku is quit cool and for filestorage you have to use AWS S3 or any other cloud service.

Comment: @SimonFranzen Agreed lol I still use Heroku for some projects. For this project I was using BoltDB for a cacheing layer so s3 didn't really fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's `standard` databases and above require SSL connections as of April, 2016. You can see the Changelog entry [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/852). You were able to use the same application code on a `hobby` database because they do not have the same restriction.